# Problems with creating hook that updates XML

Tags: xml

I have been working on a plugin for Wordpress, that updates an XML file with elements from the post. I have used a third party plugin to create the field for the XML, and so far that is working.

I am having a lot of trouble with the XML and the hook itself. I am using a DomDocument example from php4every1.com, and that works whenever I run it seperately in a php-file. However, if I include it within a function, that is hooked to the publishing of a post in wordpress, I get the following error: "The plugin generated 1 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “*headers already sent*” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin." and nothing more happens. The function including the XML will not run at all, and I have no idea why.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

add_action('publish_post','update_xml');

function update_xml(){

  $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
  $xml->formatOutput = true; 
  $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
  $xml->load('fruits.xml');

  //Get item Element 
  $element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('item')->item(0);

  //Load child elements 
  $name = $element->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0); 
  $price = $element->getElementsByTagName('price')->item(0); 
  $count = $element->getElementsByTagName('count')->item(0);

  //Change values 
  $name->nodeValue = 'Orange'; 
  $price->nodeValue = 14.33;

  //Create new element 
  $newCount = $xml->createElement('count', 10);

  //Replace old elements with new 
  $element->replaceChild($name, $name); 
  $element->replaceChild($price, $price); 
  $element->replaceChild($newCount, $count);

  //Create one new item element 
  $newItem = $xml->createElement('item'); 
  $newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('name', 'hest')); 
  $newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('price', 10.59)); 
  $newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('count', 131));

  //Add it to fruits element 
  $xml->getElementsByTagName('fruits')->item(0)->appendChild($newItem); 
  $xml->save('fruits.xml');

}

?>
```

and the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <fruits>

<item>
    <name>Apple</name>
    <price>10.25</price>
    <count>15</count>
</item>

</fruits>
```

As I said, the above works whenever I am running it in a seperate php-file without the hook and the function, but inside the hook in the plugin, it breaks. I am pretty new at programming, php and wordpress, so I bet I am overlooking something silly, but what?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I get this error when activating the plugin: "The plugin generated 1 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin."

Comment: _will not run at all_ - are you completely sure about this? It might be running, but not doing what you think it should. That would be entirely different issue.

Comment: @Rarst: pretty much. The XML code works on its own, but inside the function it doesn't. Anything outside works - I can debug with echo there, but nothing happens inside. Also, I get this error when activating the plugin:"The plugin generated 1 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1 character output error is probably because you have a single space before `<?php` or after `?>`.

As far as it not doing anything, where is the fruits.xml file? this line:

```
$xml->load('fruits.xml');
```

in this context is looking for the file at:

```
/your/server/path/to/wp-admin/fruits.xml
```

Which I assume is not what you're expecting. Have a look at [Determining Plugin and Content Directories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories) in Codex.

Comment: This worked, thanks! There was an extra line at the end, and placing the xml-file in wp-admin made it run smoothly. I can't really figure out the correct way to link to the supposed file location (within the plugin directory), even though I have gone through your link.

Comment: Solved that too. Used `$xml->load(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/XMLTest/fruits.xml');` to point it at the correct directory. Now I just need to figure out how to append the new elements in the beginning of the XML-file.

Answer (score 0):

To extend @Milo answer slightly: The "headers already sent" message can be caused by echo statements in eg. `register_activation_hook()` functions.